# Use UIActivityViewController to trigger action inside my own app

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app, I have implemented an iPhone-to-iPhone sharing method, which I will call 'Beamer' for now.

For sharing stuff through Mail, FB, etc, I use the UIActivity View Controller.
For a logical workflow, I would like to share Beamer from that sheet as well.

When you share through Mail, you are prompted with a modal dialog, allowing you to assign recipients, type some body text, etc.

I want something like that for Beamer as well: a custom dialog, modal is fine, where the user can do some last minute interaction.
Is such possible? Studying some code, I think the

```
- (void) performActivity {}
```

is intended to do that, but so far I have only found references to external apps.
How do I refer to my own app? And how do I pass on parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I should have searched better/differently:
Although I'm still struggling a bit to make it work, [this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369911/how-can-i-present-a-modalviewcontroller-from-a-uiactivity-item-picked-from-uiact) answers my question.